# fs.createWriteStream downloading to the project's root folder (Unwanted)

Tags: node.js

I am downloading a file from my MongoDB fs.files collection. In order to do so I need to pipe the Gridfs Bucket's downloadStream to the fs's createWriteFileStream. On the 'finish' of the createWriteStream I ONLY want to send the file to the client side response and NOT have fs place the file in the project's folder.

```
router.get("/download", function(req, res) {
  setTimeout(download, 1000);
  function download() {
      var bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(localDatabase())
      bucket.openDownloadStreamByName(file)
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file))
          .on('error', function(error) {
            assert.ifError(error)
          })
          .on('finish', function() {
            console.log(`Downloaded ${file}`)
            res.download(file)
            return
          })
  }
});
```

Comment: What's the value of `file`?  The path on that is how you control where the file goes.  Where do you want it to go?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can pipe directly from `openDownloadStreamByName()` to `res` and avoid the intermediate temporary file.  You will probably need to set appropriate headers to simulate the `res.download()` behavior.

Otherwise, to control the location of the temporary file, you will need to create a full path to that temporary location and use that full path with `fs.createWriteStream()`.  Then, you'll probably want to remove the temporary file after it's been sent.

Comment: @paulsender - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure.  If this didn't answer your question, please comment about which part of your question you're still confused about.